# Customized Facebook Login page in iOS or Android app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am creating an Android app that uses Facebook login using FB login button provided in SDK, but i want to create a login page as shown in the image for login purpose instead of using the FB login button of SDK.

Is it possible to create or customize the login process of Facebook for Android app?
[image]

Comment: this is bad approach !!

Comment: you can not do anything in facebook login page after click on login with facebook button

Comment: @Vishal Patoliy: messenger app is using the same approach for user login

Comment: but it is developed by facebook try to understand

Comment: Consider that this might even be prohibited by Facebook's T&C.